# Reversing operations

Tags: java, math

I am trying to reverse few operations.

My inputs are

```
1. 14
2. 8
3. 10
```

My result is

```
1. 0.14
2. 0.8
3. 0.1
```

code

```
token = 14
val = Double.parseDouble(token);
int count = countDigits(val);
val = val / Math.pow(10, count);
System.out.println("val "+val);---> results 0.14

private static int countDigits(double value) {
 int count = 0;
 while (value > 1) {
     value = value / 10;
     count++;
 }
 return count;
}
```

**case 1**

For 10 my logic is wrong.
If my value is 10, I am getting the result as 1.0 instead of .1

I am checling while(value>1) but once I add = I am not getting the correct result.

**case 2**

Now I need to convert 0.14 back to 14 and .8 to 8.

What will be the best option?

Should I count the number of digits after decimal and multiply with Math.pow or any other better way.
Whether counting of decimal point is possible?

Comment: Your guess sounds correct.  Did you try it? Does it produce the desired result?

Comment: You need to use BigDecimal. A double can never accurately represent all base-10 numbers as a fraction (because it is a binary fraction with floating point), so whatever algorithm you use, it will not work for all numbers (and neither will the algorithm above work for all numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double d = 0.18;
String numberD = String.valueOf(d);
numberD = numberD.substring ( numberD.indexOf ( "." ) + 1);
System.out.println(numberD); // Print as String
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(numberD)); // print as Integer

//Output
 18
```

Comment: But if my value is 4.0E-4..I am not getting 4 as my result.It shows java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0E-4"

Answer (score 2):

Just Do this:

```
    val = val * Math.pow(10, count);
    Double d = new Double(val);
    int i = d.intValue();
```

Comment: It is returning zero

Comment: double val = Double.parseDouble("8");          int count = countDigits(val);  
        val = val / Math.pow(10, count);  
        System.out.println("val " + val);//        --- > results 0.14  
        val = val * Math.pow(10, count);  
        Double d = new Double(val);  
        int i = d.intValue();  
        System.out.println("val reverse " + i);//        --- > results 14

Comment: I test this code myself ,  I am fine with this , Can I give all code to you ?

Comment: No its fine. I missed the first line. Can u check my edit in question

Comment: I checked for 10 result is 1.0 because of 10 power of 1 is 10 and your value is also 10 then same value divide result is 1 , result object is double so It will be 1.0, Check for below 10 value giving same value i.e val =1..10 and same power is 1...10 result will be 1.0 **for 5 and power is 5 result will be 1.0**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101751/discussion-between-unmesha-sreeveni-and-rahul-bhawar).

Answer (score 0):

To find value of count, use below logic:

```
    double val= 0.14;
    String text = Double.toString(Math.abs(val));
    int integerPlaces = text.indexOf('.');
    int count= text.length() - integerPlaces - 1;
```

Now,

```
 int originalValue=(int) (val * Math.pow(10, count));
```